# Splitting a data frame in R

Tags: r, split

I have uploaded a tab delimited file into R as a data frame. When I tried to call a specific row from the data frame I realized that the column names were all connected (V1...V2...V3...V4) and when I tried to fix this I realized the columns are all stuck together and I don't know how to split them properly. For reference it is 4 columns and 325 observations.

This is how I read the file in:

```
read.table(file.choose(), sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
```

I have already tried:

```
as.data.frame(matrix(softball,ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
as.data.frame(matrix(softball,ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

as well as reading the file in using `readLines()` and using `strsplit()`.

Comment: Are you sure the file is tab delimited? You probably just need to read it in correctly  rather than trying to split it.

Comment: Give a link to the original file if the content can be public.

Comment: Im not sure what else kind of delimiter it would be, I did try to read it in as a space delimited file and it gave me an error, also the file is not a public file.

Comment: @AmandaAlley - can you take the first 10 lines, replace all the data with `X`s in a text editor and paste that as an example?